# Using the factory design pattern to create a specific instance of one type

Tags: c++, factory

I'm using C++ to write a program for an arduino with a touchscreen display. In this I have a Display class which in a basic sense allows me to work with the data read from the pins on the board, and the images on the screen together. With this I have a Screen class that actually holds all the information I want to display at a given time, however I have many different screens I can swap between.

I want to make a factory class or classes that will allow me to make the specific Screens that can be displayed in one place, but I'm not sure what the best option for this is. Since every object I want to make is of the type Screen, I think the best way to do this is one factory class with methods for creating every different Screen, determined by an enumerator passed to the factory class.

However, my research into proper factory implementation is leaving me a little confused, as most examples seem to have a parent factory class with multiple subclasses for the different objects being created, or even just one subclass, which makes me unsure of the parent class's purpose. That was my initial plan, but it feels unnecessary to me now, although possibly a little cleaner, this would add a large number of classes to my project when I feel it could all be handled in one.

Sorry if this isn't enough information to provide a solid answer, but I would appreciate any help!

Comment: This is somewhat opinion-based, but I personally see no problem with your suggestion.  KISS and all that.

Comment: Can you add some sample code? My understanding is that you have a class with a function like `Screen* create(ScreenEnum e)` and the users supply the actual enum. That would hide the actual Screen type, but the users are still in control which kind of screen they want.

Comment: @Jens That was my interpretation, yes.

Comment: The point of the polymorphism is that you can exchange the factory object without changing the using class, even at runtime. It fully decouples object construction from and encapsulates the construction logic. However, I usually use a more lightweight approach with a `std::function<Screem* (ScreenEnum e)>` instead of a base class, or even a template type if static polymorphism improves  the design.

Comment: If your code won't be helped by using a base class and derived classes for the different screens, then don't. No need to add complexity if you don't need it.

Comment: @super that's exactly what I was thinking, thanks for reassuring me
and to Jens you got it right there, with some minor changes like names that's exactly what my function call will look like